# Read file at byte location

Tags: go

I need to read a file at a specific location, given by a byte offset.

```
filePath := "test_file.txt"
byteOffset := 6
// Read file
```

How can I achieve this, if possible without reading the whole file in memory ?

Comment: [File.Seek](https://godoc.org/os#File.Seek)

Comment: What have you tried? What problems do you have? You just need to open the file and use [`File.Seek()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Seek).

Answer (score 4):

> [Package os](https://golang.org/pkg/os/)
>
> ```
> import "os"
> ```
>
> [func (*File) Seek](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Seek)
>
> ```
> func (f *File) Seek(offset int64, whence int) (ret int64, err error)
> ```
>
> Seek sets the offset for the next Read or Write on file to offset,
>   interpreted according to whence: 0 means relative to the origin of the
>   file, 1 means relative to the current offset, and 2 means relative to
>   the end. It returns the new offset and an error, if any. The behavior
>   of Seek on a file opened with O_APPEND is not specified.

---

> [Package io](https://golang.org/pkg/io/)
>
> ```
> import "io"
> ```
>
> Seek whence values.
>
> ```
> const (
>     SeekStart   = 0 // seek relative to the origin of the file
>     SeekCurrent = 1 // seek relative to the current offset
>     SeekEnd     = 2 // seek relative to the end 
> )
> ```

---

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    filePath := "test.file"
    byteOffset := 6
    f, err := os.Open(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    _, err = f.Seek(int64(byteOffset), io.SeekStart)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    buf := make([]byte, 16)
    n, err := f.Read(buf[:cap(buf)])
    buf = buf[:n]
    if err != nil {
        if err != io.EOF {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", buf)
}
```

Output:

```
$ cat test.file
0123456789
$ go run seek.go
6789

$
```